# What is the most efficient way to earn money for my magical horse?

Tags: secret-of-the-magic-crystals

In "Secret of the Magic Crystals", money is a key factor: you need to upgrade the building and the equipment in the stable. But you receive very little money (about 50 gold) from the races. What is the most efficient way to earn money?

[image: magic crystals screenshot]

Comment: I think your question "What is the most efficient way to earn money for my magical horse?" epitomises this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have as many trained horses as possible. Then take part in races simultaneously.